# Mt. Gox rehabilitation status? How much % are the creditors getting back?

Tags: mtgox

What is the status of the Mt. Gox rehabilitation? I know that on October 5th they allowed creditors to start applying for reimbursement, but how much reimbursement?

For example, if the creditor had 100 bitcoins on Mt. Gox what will they get back? From what I understand the creditor can choose a cash reimbursement or bitcoins. How much would they get in each case?

Comment: https://cryptoslate.com/mt-gox-exchange-releases-guideline-for-btc-repayment/

Answer (score 3):

It's complicated, due to the mix of bankruptcy proceedings (which has one set of legal requirements), and the civil rehabilitation proceedings that came later. The payout will depend on the amounts and ratios between currencies.

I suggest using this calculator: https://blog.wizsec.jp/2021/02/mtgox-claim-calculator.html

You have the choice to either get either paid now (early lump sum, giving you roughly 21% of holdings, after some corrections), or wait for completion of a number of pending legal challenges which, if successful, could result in a lower percentage than 21%, but likely a slightly higher number. It's unclear how long those legal challenges will take, however.

You then also have the choice to be paid out either in just fiat, or in a combination of fiat + cryptocurrency. My understanding is that this choice does not impact the (fiat) value of what you get paid out, just the manner in which it is paid.

Answer (score 0):

You will get back about 1 in 3 when talking about coins you had there.
Fiat currency you had there will be repaid 100%.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/87325)

Comment: ?? How does this NOT answer. 33% for the coins, 100% for the cash. It can't really be clearer than this no ?

Comment: I think this answer looks like it's poor quality to people, because it is so short. It could probably be improved by adding a source for these figures and explaining the process in a couple more sentences. Also, “money” is ambiguous, since Bitcoin might also be considered money.